# What problems does Steak gem solve?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, capybara, acceptance-testing

I have few integration tests in Capybara+RSpec for a Rails project. Today I encountered [Steak](https://github.com/cavalle/steak) gem that meant to be pure Ruby alternative to Cucumber. Though at first glance I don't see any value in either of them. For me it looks like Steak renames `describe` to `feature` and `it` to `scenario`. Personally i would prefer describe and it because i got used to them and i don't see any reason to make my acceptance tests to look different from my controller or model tests.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steak *is* RSpec+Capybara. Steak is also these three other things: the name for this Acceptance BDD approach (so that people knows how you test just but using that name), a gem that makes that approach as convenient as possible (so that you don't have to create the same directories and helpers for each project) and a community of developers using it (so that if you have problems, you know where to ask).

For additional rationale, you may want to check out the "Why Steak?" section in [the project's README](https://github.com/cavalle/steak#readme), or this other [StackOverflow awswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773096/what-does-steak-add-beyond-just-using-capybara-and-rspec-in-rails-testing/4773622#4773622).